# Is using an empty while loop to increment a value ok?

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I need to decrement an integer to the highest int that is not in the array but lower than 6. I did this:

```js
var x = 6;
var arr = [3,5,6];
while(arr.indexOf(--x) > -1){}
console.log(x); //4

x = 6;
arr = [4,5,6];
while(arr.indexOf(--x) > -1){}
console.log(x); //3
```

Is this acceptable? Should I use an empty while loop to do this...

***Edit --> ES6 is not an option.

***Edit 2 --> The values in the array will never be higher than six in this scenario. (The max value is known)

***Edit 3 --> I see three answers that are great.  I marked CodeManiac's answer as accepted for three reasons.

1. He was first to answer.
2. His answer seems to be just as efficient as the other answers.
3. He shows both ES6 and non ES6 implementations.

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: Just trying to get the max integer not in that array but lower than 6

Comment: what you will like as output if your array is `[10, 15, 20]` for example? Max integer not in array will be `19` but is greater then `6`.

Comment: I mean technically you can do that, but it's not what I would call standard. Maybe you could think up a better way to accomplish the same thing with easier to understand code.

Comment: @Shidersz The values in the array will never be higher than six.

Comment: @Chipster That is why I asked this question. I'm trying to think of a better way.

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable, though it would look better, if you wrote: `while(arr.indexOf(--x) > -1);` However, [Array.reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) would most likely do this particular task more efficiently, and would also be more readable.

Comment: Fair point. GBrandt's answer seems close, but as you said doesn't work completely. I don't know. I'm not coming up with anything better off the top of my head. I feel like a for loop and an if should do the trick, but can't articulate what exactly those ifs and fors should be.

Comment: Side note: if you're doing this more than once, I recommend a function, but I'm guessing you knew that already... 

Comment: @Teemu I like your suggestion you should make an answer.

Comment: @Chipster yes more than once would need a function.. :D this code is only an example.

Comment: @ZachPainter what is desired output in case `x` value is higher than highest value in array ?

Comment: @CodeManiac The value in the array will never be higher than 6.

Comment: @ZachPainter i am asking if value of `x` is higher than highest value in array. i mean `x` is greater than `6`

Comment: @CodeManiac value x will never be higher in this scenario

Comment: your last point three violates your first point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will do it like this. i will not use indexOf.

Here idea is

- First sort the array in descending order.
- Now match the value from `0`<sup>th</sup> index.
- If we find match we reduce `value` by `1` and increase `index` by `1`
- As soon as we find non matching value we break out of while loop and return that value.

```js
const lessthan = (arr,value) => {
  arr = Object.values(arr.reduce((op,inp)=>((op[inp] ? op[inp] : op[inp]=inp),op),{}))
  arr.sort((a, b) => b-a)
  let i = 0;
  while( true ) {
    if( value === arr[i] ){
      --value;
      i++;
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }

}

console.log(lessthan([4,5,6],6))
console.log(lessthan([3,4,6],6))
console.log(lessthan([3,6,6],6))
```

> ES6 is not supported you can just change variable assignment to normal function like the below example.

```js
function lessthan(arr,value) {
  arr.sort((a,b) => b-a)
  var i=0;
  while(true){
    if(value === arr[i]){
      --value;
      i++
    } else {
      return value
    }
  }
}


console.log(lessthan([4,5,6],6))
console.log(lessthan([3,4,6],6))
```

Comment: 1. ES6 is not compatible with my users needs... 2. I'm not sure that this code is any more efficient than what I'm doing. and it is more lines.

Comment: 1.You can easily change it to normal function, 2. yes it is because in you function you're using indexOf which will try to loop through complete array each time. whereas this will not

Comment: This is good.. I may accept it as answer...  I want to see what others have to suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I forgot that indexOf was looping through the array for each value.

Comment: @ZachPainter This will actually fail, if the array is `[5,6,6]` (returns `5` in that case). If that array case is not possible, then you can go with this, ofcourse.

Comment: @Teemu using `Set` will fix this one too. but not sure about the case

Comment: @ZachPainter do you have any such case of repeated values ?

Comment: I assume the code is for dice rolling, if that's correct, the double six is possible. Anyway, ES6 was not option, hence `Set` is out of the limits.

Comment: @Teemu You can use polyfill for `Set` or simply you can use reduce to achieve that. you can see the updated one

Comment: Repeated values are not possible in this example but it is a plus to code for them.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution based on **@CodeManiac** answer but uses a recursive approach. However, we will need as a pre-condition that the array is sorted in descending order. You can do that with:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => b - a);
```

## Recursive approach:

```js
const customFind = (arr, maxVal) =>
{
    const f1nd = (sArr, v, idx = 0) =>
    {
        if (idx > 0 && sArr[idx] === sArr[idx - 1])
            return f1nd(sArr, v, idx + 1);

        if (sArr[idx] !== v)
            return v;

        return f1nd(sArr, v - 1, idx + 1);
    }

    return f1nd(arr.sort((a, b) => b - a), maxVal);
}

console.log(customFind([4,5,6], 6));
console.log(customFind([1,5,2], 6));
console.log(customFind([6,2,5], 6));
console.log(customFind([5,6,6], 6));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: @Teemu too much restrictions. Updated again... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort()` to have values in descending order. Then use `find()` method to find first which will `return` the first value which will meet the given conditions

```js
function func(array,val){
  let sorted = array.sort((a,b) => b - a)
  return sorted.find((a,i,x) => ((x[i] !== x[i-1] -1) && x[i] < val)) + 1 || sorted[sorted.length - 1] - 1;
}
console.log(func([3,5,6],6));
console.log(func([4,5,6],6));
console.log(func([3,4,6],6))
```

Comment: I know i can use a function... That is beside the point. I'm trying to find a better way to get the expected value of x than using an while(array.indexOf(--val) > -1);

Comment: The function returns the wrong values.  I need the function to return the highest number that is NOT in the array that is less than or equal to 6. close though. :)

Comment: @Zach Painter Ok I edited it again. Don't just accept mine. I am just want to see if its ok.

Comment: This is mindblowing, you're using `find` to find a value which doesn't exist = ).

Comment: @Teemu thanks but I think its ugly. Shidersz solutions is best

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want to find the max value, less than the biggest value, not found in the array. [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is an array method to reduce the values in an array to a single value, without mutating the array itself. The task could be done by using [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight), which makes the reduction in the reversed order. Providing the values are in ascending order, the code could be something like below:

```js
function findSMax (arr, max) {
    arr.sort(function (a, b) {return a - b;});
    return arr.reduceRight(function (acc, curr) {
        return (acc > curr) ? acc : --curr;
    }, max);
}
console.log(findSMax([2, 5, 6], 6));
```

Here the first value of `acc` is passed to the callback as the second argument of `reduceRight`. `acc` is the value, which is passed to the next round in the iteration, and it becomes to the return value at the end of the loop.

In the callback we check, if the stored value (`acc`) is greater than the current array value, and when it is, preserve the current value of `acc` (we've iterated past the target value), otherwise store a value which is the current array value reduced by one (it's the next expected value). This way `acc` will stay at a value, which will have no bigger gap than one to the next bigger value in the array.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnLz7q8w/1/) to play with.

Answer (score 1):

Right, it is valid code and you could replace the empty block statement with a semicolon, to indicate a finished statement.

```js
var x = 6,
    array = [3, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12];

while (array.indexOf(--x) > -1);

console.log(x); // 4
```